# How do I install a Python module for "Apple system Python"?

Tags: python, matplotlib, qgis

I'm trying to install QGis (from the Kyngchaos packages) and it fails with the error "QGIS requires the Matplotlib python module.".

I'm pretty sure the problem is that I need to install matplotlib for Apple's system Python, so that it can be found by QGis ([see background](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/72073/7785)).

I'm a bit confused by the error, because I just open python at the command line, it finds matplotlib without any problems:

```
$ python 
>>> import matplotlib
>>>
```

I guess the Python I've opened isn't the "Apple Python" - indeed `which python` gives me `/opt/local/bin/python`.

But if I look in `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages` as the answer above suggests, I don't see matplotlib there.

So, how can I install matplotlib for the Apple's system Python?

Comment: What are you using to install matplotlib? Git? There are instructions in README.osx that may be able to help you.

Answer (score 2):

Install matplotlib from here: http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/python. It will put matplotlib in `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages` That's where Qgis looks for it.

Comment: The link now leads to a page with no result!

Comment: @arniotaki are you sure? I just checked and it works for me. Matplotlib is a little further down on that page.

Comment: Oh yes! Now it works! It seems that there was a problem yesterday that is fixed now. Sorry for that!

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem with you. After spending hours searching on the net for solutions here is what i found:

I found that great link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oAC5K8jMfQI

which describes you in detail what to do.So you just have to download:

1. GDAL 1-10 Complete from here: http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/frameworks and install first GDAL Complete and then NumPy and then:
2. The right version of QGIS for your mac version from here: http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/archive

Good luck. For me it worked!